# How to ask links or turtles or variables that are formed at a certain time?

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling

Thank you for the help you provide on the community. So I am trying to create links between agents that come within a radius of 1 of each other. If the turtles do not come within a radius of 1 of each other for 16 ticks, the link automatically dies.  So technically, one link might start at tick 200 and has to die at tick 216 unless it is "renewed" however another link can start at tick 250 and has to die at link 266. However, if I use ask links it changes for all the links.

So my question is how to say something like : ask the link that was formed at tick xx set die time at xx+16 if ticks = xx+16 [die].

Also how do I renew the links so when two agents with a link come in contact again they set a new start and die time for the link between them?

Thank you very much. I know I should only ask one question at a time but I guess they might be related and can be solved together. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two equivalent ways come to my mind.

One way mimics the logic that you expressed in your question:

```
links-own [
  time-to-die
]


to create-links
  ask one-of turtles [
    create-links-with one-of other turtles [
      set time-to-die (ticks + 16)
    ]
  ]
end


to check-condition
  ask links [
    if (link-length <= 1) [
      set time-to-die (ticks + 16)
    ]

    if (time-to-die = ticks) [die]
  ]
end
```

The other way creates a counter where each link keeps track of how long its two ends have been apart:

```
links-own [
  time-apart
]


to check-condition
  ask links [
    ifelse (link-length > 1)
      [set time-apart time-apart + 1]
      [set time-apart 0]

    if (time-apart = 16) [die]
  ]
end
```

If we want to be precise, the first approach will be a bit lighter because links will not have to set the value of `time-to-die` at every tick (while, in the second approach, links set the value of `time-apart` at every tick), but I guess this advantage might be so small that you should probably just prefer the one that best fits the overall logic of your model.

In any case, the key point is that there is no problem in asking all links to update & check their condition: each link will perform its calculations and checks based on its own situation, so there is no problem in handling different links being born and having to die at different points in time.

Comment: Superb ! This is a great and a very helpful answer.  Thank you very very much !!!!!!!

Comment: FYI, I chose this as the answer but still need rep to make it count. Thanks a million again !

Comment: @DailyReader Glad it helped! What you are referring to is [upvoting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), but you can accept the answer by clicking on the v-shaped checkmark below the two voting buttons - this will also signal that your issue has been solved